Conda path is not properly read in VScode bash terminal
When running any conda command in a VScode bash terminal, I get the following error, e.g. :
$conda env list
bash: C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\miniconda3\Scripts: No such file or directory

However, all conda commands (env list, activate, ...) work fine in a cmd terminal !
It turns out that my username starts with a 'f', so the path looks like "C:\Users\f...\AppData...", but the '\f' seems to be read as an escaped character, which leads to "C:\Users♀...".
Any idea on how to fix this ?

I finally solved it by adding (I hope as strangely, the problem is not constant...)
"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.enabled": false

in User Settings (json)

Thank you very much. After many hours of searching and trying things this is the only thing that worked for me. Running command of conda env list, conda activate an_env kept saying miniconda3\Scripts is a directory wihle using VS Code integrated Git Bash terminal. With Git Bash terminal launched outside of VS Code, all worked as expected.
